# RestEasy UTF-8 Response in WildFly

Tags: java, utf-8, wildfly, resteasy

My wildfly server is started via standalone-full.xml configuration. In standalone.bat:

```
set "SERVER_OPTS=--server-config=standalone-full.xml"
```

And when I want to return the Russian text, I get something like the following:
[image]

Response:

```
...
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN + ";charset=utf-8")
...
return Response.status(200).entity("Русский текст.").build();
...
```

I have seen similar topics, but the solutions did not help me

Comment: Do you see that result in a browser or some other client? It's working for me on Linux.

Comment: I see this result in browser, on Windows. But before i set "SERVER_OPTS=--server-config=standalone-full.xml", all worked correctly